# The type or namespace 'IRange' could not be found

Tags: c#, .net, compiler-errors

I'm using C#.net 4.0 with Visual Studio 2010. I am getting the error

> Error 10  The type or namespace name 'IRange' could not be found (are
>   you missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)   C:\git\emtexporter\EMTExporter.IRepository\IRangeRepository.cs  11  27  EMTExporter.IRepository

IRange is an interface in the project EMTExporter.IEntities and the project IEntities builds successfully. IRange.cs has the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Wiggle.EMTExporter.IEntities;

namespace Wiggle.CategoryXMLExporter.IEntities
{
    interface IRange
    {
        long ID { get; }
        Dictionary<ILanguage, string> rangeNames { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The problem occurs in IRangeRepository.cs which has the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Wiggle.EMTExporter.IEntities;

namespace CategoryXMLExporter.IRepository
{
    interface IRangeRepository
    {
        Dictionary<string,IList<IRange>> getAllRanges();
    }
}
```

I am referencing EMTExporter.IEntities in the IRepository project.
I have no idea what could be going wrong!

edit: the issue was that the project was changed from CategoryXMLExporter to EMTExporter, but I hadn't updated the Assembly name and Default namespace of the project. Updated that, made the interface public and now it works!

Comment: An interface is not public by default. So add a `public` modifier to `IRange`. However, the error message is different on my system, so it might not be the fault you're looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your interface is not public try the following

```
public interface IRange
```

Answer (score 2):

The default [accessibility level](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173121.aspx) top level classes and interfaces is `internal`, not `public`, so if these are in different projects, it won't be visible.

> Classes and structs that are declared directly within a namespace (in other words, that are not nested within other classes or structs) can be either public or internal. Internal is the default if no access modifier is specified.

```
namespace Wiggle.CategoryXMLExporter.IEntities
{
    public interface IRange
    {
        long ID { get; }
        Dictionary<ILanguage, string> rangeNames { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`IRange` is in the namespace `Wiggle.CategoryXMLExporter.IEntities` so you will need to reference that. Also make the Interface `public`

Comment: Just figured out the problem. The project was renamed from CategoryXMLExporter to EMTExporter, I went to the properties for EMTExporter.IEntities and changed the assembly name to Wiggle.EMTExporter.IEntities and made the interface public, which solved it!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the namespace `Wiggle.CategoryXMLExporter.IEntities` to your using clauses, because `IRange` is defined there:

```
using Wiggle.CategoryXMLExporter.IEntities;
```

Also, if it's in a different assembly, you need to make it `public`.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what has been mentioned above, sometimes you may need to ensure the referenced library is configured as being built under the selected active configuration and platform.

1. In Visual Studio 2012 or 2013, right-click on the Solution and chose "Configuration Manager".
2. For the selected "Active Solution Configuration" (e.g. "Debug" or "Release") and "Active Solution Platform" (e.g. "Any CPU", "x64", "x86", or "ARM") ensure the project that contains your interfaces and any of its dependencies have "Build" checked.